# How to calculate determinant of a (N-1) order Matrix?

Tags: matrices, determinant

For $n \geq 2,$ consider the following square matrix of order $(n-1)$

\begin{array}{cccccc}
3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 \\
1 & 4 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 5 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 6 & & 1 \\
& & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & n+1
\end{array}

Find its determinant using only elementary row operations and denote it by $A_{n}$. Hence or otherwise, check whether the sequence $\left\{^{A_{n}} / n_{1}\right\}_{n>2}$ is bounded

Basically I am getting no clue. 
Should I proceed with Echelon  Form?

Comment: is $\left\{\frac{A_n}{n-1}\right\}_{n>2}$ meant to be a sequence notation or the fraction part?

Comment: No, It is meant to be sequence notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic idea:
1. We get rid of $1$s except for the first row
2. We get rid of $1$s in the first row
3. We consider $(A)_{1,1}$ as the rest is known

So 1. we subtract the 1st row from every other row:
$$\begin{align*}
\left|\begin{array}{cccccc}
3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 \\
1 & 4 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 5 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 6 & & 1 \\
& & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & n+1
\end{array}\right|
&=
\left|\begin{array}{cccccc}
 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & & 1 \\
-2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & 4 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & 0 & 5 & & 0 \\
& & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
-2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n
\end{array}\right|
\end{align*}$$
2. we subtract each row (say $k$th), multiplied by $\frac{1}{k+1}$ from the first row:
$$=
\left|\begin{array}{cccccc}
 a_{1,1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & & 0 \\
-2 & 3 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & 4 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-2 & 0 & 0 & 5 & & 0 \\
& & & & \ddots & \vdots \\
-2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & n
\end{array}\right|$$
3. As it's lower-triangular now, we consider $a_{1,1}$ as 
$|A|=a_{1,1}\prod\limits_{k=3}^n k$,
$a_{1,1}=3+2\sum\limits_{k=3}^n \frac{1}{k}$

Comment: It would be better if you throughly explain!

Comment: Please see the edits. Is the part about sequence needed to be written out or it's obvious?

Comment: [determinant of lower triangular matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1243887) is a well-known result, as for an upper triangular too. On $a_{1,1}$: It was $3$ on step 1. Then we subtracted from it $-2$ for each oher row, multiplied by $\frac{1}{k+1}$ for $k$ from $2$ to $n-1$ -- the same thing as added $2\cdot\frac{1}{k}$ for $k$ from $3$ to $n$. Sure it was step 3, not 2? Or the prod/sum notations?

Comment: sorry! step 3 is clear to me! I am unable to understand about Step 2, why we subtract each row (say kth), multiplied by 1k+1 from the first row and how is it working?

Comment: Is the legality of such operation needed to be shown somehow? Why: to get rid of the $1$s in the first row. How it's working: on $k$th row (for $k>1$) now on the step 2 (before we proceed) there are only $2$ elements $\ne 0$, namely $a_{k,1}=-2$ and $a_{k,k}=k+1$, so we want $a_{k,k}$ to eliminate $a_{1,k}$ therefore the constant is chosen to be $\frac{1}{k+1}$ so that $a_{1,k}-\frac{1}{k+1}a_{k,k}=1-\frac{1}{k+1}\cdot(k+1)=0$

Comment: great.now it is cleared!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108429/discussion-between-statistics-and-alexey-burdin).